# Cant close dropdown menu on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, nav

I want the menu to be closed when you click on an item in dropdown menu. At this moment, the menu closes only when the you click on the menu button.

Link to website >>> http://www.glassmania.pl/PROA5/index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {

        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button"><span></span><span></span><span></span>' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.slideUp().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.slideDown().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').slideDown();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideUp();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideDown();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');


      });
    };

    $(".navy").menumaker({
        title: "Navigation",
        format: "multitoggle"
    });


        $('#menu-button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });     


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without working example but i'll try to help.

I thinks this is what you need:

```
$('.page-scroll').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('ul').removeClass('open');
});
```

page-scroll class is your menu item and when user clicks on it we remove open class from parent ul element.